# Read Temperature from BLE Thermometer using Android App

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf-connect

I have purchased a BLE thermometer and developing an android app to read the temperature. I installed nRF connect and was able to see the BLE device listed with all its services. The temperature measurement characteristic is marked as Indicate. I don't seem to find how to get this indicate in nRF. Nothing happens when I read the temperature using the BLE device. This temperature is not reflected in nRF logs.

I developed an android app and was able to scan this BLE device, connect to it and enable indications. But the onCharacteristicChanged never gets invoked when I measure the temperature using the BLE device. My code is below.

```js
private final UUID temperatureServiceUuid = UUID.fromString("00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private final UUID temperatureMeasureUuid = UUID.fromString("00002A1C-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private final UUID temperatureDescriptorUuid = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) {
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(temperatureDescriptorUuid);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor, BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private final UUID temperatureServiceUuid = UUID.fromString("00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private final UUID temperatureMeasureUuid = UUID.fromString("00002A1C-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private final UUID temperatureDescriptorUuid = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

private void setNotificationTemp(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
    BluetoothGattService temperatureService = gatt.getService(temperatureServiceUuid);
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic temperatureChar = temperatureService.getCharacteristic(temperatureMeasureUuid);
    gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(temperatureChar, true)

    BluetoothGattDescriptor temperatureDescriptor = temperatureChar.getDescriptor(temperatureDescriptorUuid);
    gatt.writeDescriptor(temperatureDescriptor, BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: Hello Vishnu! Thanks for your response. The real reason was because the thermometer manufacturer was not using the standard temperature service. Rather they were indicating the temperature in another custom service, with the temperature value being encoded. That's why I wasn't receiving any notification. I was barking up the wrong tree so to speak :)